# Series convergence and divergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

> Suppose that sum of $\{a_n\}$ converges and that $a_n > 0$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$. Prove that
>   sum of $\{1/a_n\}$ diverges.

I tried using contradiction but couldn't come to any conclusion. I also tried using the fact that $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies$ $\lim a_n = 0$.

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: Those are all good things to try.  For instance, if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, can it also be true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

If the sum of $\{a_n\}$ converges then by the divergence test, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.  This means that (with limit definitions), $\exists N\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $\forall n>N$, we have $|a_n| < 1$. Thus, $\forall n>N$, we have $|\frac{1}{a_n}|>1$.  Ergo, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\frac{1}{a_n}|>1$. Regardless of the sign, its a given that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}\ne 0$, and so the sum of $\{\frac{1}{a_n}\}$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

$(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j)(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{a_k})
\ge n
$
because you always have the
$n$ terms with
$j=k$.

Therefore if
$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j
< M
$,
then
$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{a_k}
\ge \dfrac{n}{\sum_{j=1}^n a_j}
\gt \dfrac{n}{M}
$
which diverges.